# Dynamically set variables by string in react functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I want to use the react-query library, but this library is only usable in functional components. I currently have a class component which dynamically sets the state of fields, based on a string. Eg (simplified, in reality it gets the fields from a REST-call which results in different fields every time, that's why it needs to be dynamic):

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.primaryFields = ["username"];
        this.uiFields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email"];
        this.state = {}
        this.primaryFields.map(x => {
            this.state[x] = "no key given";
        })

        this.uiFields.map(x => {
            this.state[x] = "";
        })   
    }
    ...
    ...
 }
```

But since hooks can't be used in a loop, nested functions or in callback functions, i don't have a way of dynamically setting the state with:

```
useState()
```

Is there a way to dynamically set state with hooks in functional components in a same way i do that in my class components?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) and its hook [useImmer](https://github.com/immerjs/use-immer). For this example it may be overkill to add a library, but as your state changes get more complex, it may be simpler to write `updateState(state => { state[fieldName] = value })` than `setState(state => ({ ...state, [fieldName]: value }))`. Especially when you deal with arrays and nested objects. Let the library deal with the problem of mutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what this has to do with react-query, but you can also just make one `useState` object that holds your value:

```
uiFields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]
const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => uiFields.reduce(acc => {
    acc[v] = "no key given" 
    return acc
}, {}))

const updateState = (fieldName, value) =>
    setState(previousState => ({ ...previousState, [fieldName]: value })
```

This is a bit more convoluted, because you need to always return the full object when calling `setState`, as opposed to the class based version, where you can return a partial object.

But now you can call `updateState("myKey", "myValue")` and it should work like the class-based equivalent.

For more complex state management, there is also `useReducer`, which might come in handy here.

Comment: Perfect, this is what i was looking for. My app now dynamically creates a whole list of form-fields which i can couple to a dynamically generated state.